# Run aave test suite locally on ganache [Change network hardhat to ganache]

Tags: dapps, hardhat, ganache, aave

This is aave protocol v2: https://github.com/aave/protocol-v2

They have a built-in test suite. Running `npm run test` runs all the tests cases properly. But this runs on `hardhat` node. I need to change the network to `ganache`. Can't find the configuration codes to run on `ganache`.

Any idea where or on which file I can change the network configuration? Any hint would save my day. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1**

If you don't want to manually start and stop Ganache every time, you can use the hardhat-ganache plugin.

This plugin creates a network called ganache, and automatically starts and stops Ganache before and after running your tests and scripts.

o use it, you have to install it with npm

```
npm install --save-dev @nomiclabs/hardhat-ganache
```

and add this line at the beginning of your hardhat.config.js

```
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-ganache");
```

Finally, you can run your tests with

```
npx hardhat --network ganache test
```

**Option 2**
In your hardhat.config file include the ganache info in the networks part:

```
module.exports = {
  defaultNetwork: "ganache",
  networks: {
    ganache: {
      gasLimit: 6000000000,
      defaultBalanceEther: 10,
    },
  },
};
```

Finally, you can run your tests with

```
npx hardhat test --network ganache
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. But I am getting this error on Option 1.
`Error in plugin @nomiclabs/hardhat-ganache: Ganache network only works with localhost`.

Comment: Getting this error on option 2: `Error in plugin @nomiclabs/hardhat-ganache: Ganache network config is invalid: value.accounts is not an array` 

Can you have a look at this config file and provide me a direction? I am out of ideas.
https://github.com/aave/protocol-v2/blob/master/hardhat.config.ts

Comment: There seems to be an issue with naming the network as `ganache`. When I changed it to `ganache_local` it deployed properly without that error.